# Merge file of certain coordinates to shapefile of cities using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, merge, addlayer

I am using ArcMap 10.8.

I have a shapefile of cities with their info like name, population and area so I have calculated each city's density of population. Now I have some certain coordinates and I add them to my ArcGIS and can "SEE" which city each point belongs to (so what density of population is for each point). But I want "an EXPORT" that gives me a table with my points and shows to which city they belong so what every point's population density is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

[Spatial Join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm):

> Joins attributes from one feature to another based on the spatial
> relationship

Or [Intersect](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm):

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features. Features or
> portions of features which overlap in all layers and/or feature
> classes will be written to the output feature class

Comment: thank you so much. I used Spatial Join but it didn't work properly and gave me columns of "null" values.